# Cron action not working as expected in GitHub Action

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to schedule git cron job action every 5 minutes for my maven project. Below is my yaml configuration.

```
# This workflow will build a Java project with Maven, and cache/restore any dependencies to improve the workflow execution time
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/building-and-testing-java-with-maven

name: Java CI with Maven

on:
 schedule:
    - cron: "*/5 * * * *"

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'adopt'
        cache: maven
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
```

The execution is not even started even after 2 hrs.

Comment: Please add the proper tags for github actions instead

Comment: Why do you like to build your project every five minutes? This does not make much sense...

Comment: I am having a requirement where I have to build my project every 24 hrs(through github schedule action) to get the data from DB and create its backup in files. I am just replicating the scenario on github with dummy project (with cron action 5 mins) to validate the functionality of the cron job as I have read somewhere that this github cron schedule functionality is inconsistent.  I assume now it makes sense to you .

Comment: I have observed that it started after 3 hrs and it's not even consistent ( running at random time but not every 5 minutes) .

Comment: Thanks , Just now I checked it , there @GuiFalourd has mentioned that there is no guarantee for this cron. Is there any alternate solution for this issue?

Comment: Is it mandatory to run the workflow every 5 min? Using a higher delay (once a day or every 2h for example) should able to run the workflows as scheduled with more consistency.